# Token input on space

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tokenize

im using this bootstrap tokeninput for my search
[SOURCE files](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/)

This give me option when i type a word and press enter that word is tag, and now how to acomplish that instead enter, word became tag, when you press SPACEbar.
Want option Just like Tags have ,on stackoverlow .
If you need more details, i will provide.

UPDATE:
I FOUND THIS EXPLANATION 
To tokenize on space key, simply do this:

```
$('#field').tokenfield({ triggerKeys: [32] });
```

Where to add this line of code?
my code is:

```
<input type="text" id="Tags" class="form-control token-field" value="earth, sky" placeholder="Enter tags" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **delimiter** Keyword

**Example:**

```
 $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
    autocomplete: {
      source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
      delay: 100
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
    delimiter: [',',' ', '-', '_']
  });
```